# vba function Replace function not working

Tags: excel, vba

i have problem with .Replace() function in VBA, it doesnt give me any error but it doesnt do the job.
Here is the code:

```
MsgBox Wb3.Name    
Wb3.Worksheets(1).Columns("B").Replace _
            What:="-", Replacement:="", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Here is table in which function needs to remove "-" before values

[image]

Am i doing something wrong?

**WORKING SOLUTION:**

I was missing "LookAt:=xlPart"

```
Wb3.Worksheets(1).Columns("B").Replace _
            What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Comment: You are trying to make a negative number positive by replacing the negative sign with an empty string?

Comment: yes, but i found i was missing one part of code. I updated it with working solution

Answer (score 3):

### Abs a Range

```vb
' Reference the column.
With Wb3.Worksheets(1).Columns("B")
    ' Reference the range (exclude header) using 'Resize', 'End' and 'Offset'.
    With .Resize(.Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Offset(1)
        ' 'Abs' the range using 'Worksheet.Evaluate'
        .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate("ABS(" & .Address & ")")
    End With
End With
```

**Observations**

- The execution time for a sample of 100k rows was 0.35s while for a sample of 500k rows it was 1.2s **not dependent** on how many conversions took place, making it **largely dependent** on the number of processed cells.
- On the other hand, the replace solution (`.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart` (the remaining parameters are irrelevant) instead of `.Value = ...`) took 4.7s for 100k and 28s for 500k rows when all cells needed to be replaced and only 0.17s and 0,87s respectively when no replacement took place, additionally making the execution time **largely dependent** on the number of replacements.

Answer (score 1):

After adding **LookAt:=xlPart** it worked, so this is final code:

```
Wb3.Worksheets(1).Columns("B").Replace _
            What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```